# Streaming API Limited to 60 Follows

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have an application which connections to the twitter streaming api using the resource url https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json . Recently however the number of twitter ids I can follow seems to have been reduced to just 60! The application had been running for over a year with over 1000 twitter ids. To connect to the streaming api we use the feeb's Phirehose library https://github.com/fennb/phirehose. I am able to track over 60 user ids when I run the application on my local machine using the same twitter authentication credentials too.

Has twitter imposed some sort of rate limit on my server's IP? Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Thanks,

Mark

---- Edit

I have found a patch, by putting sleep statements between fwrite()'s which were writing parameters to the connection to twitter I was able to establish a stream with as many userids as I wanted. I'm not sure if the problem is on my end or twitter end though.

Comment: Have you already contacted Twitter?

Comment: @ComFreek Yes, although I'm waiting for a reply from them